# Redis - integer list

Tags: redis, netty, finagle

How do I push *integers* with `lpush` in a redis list type?
I want to test my finagle-redis client if it works correctly and insert manual sample data into redis like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush key:214 1 1 1
 (integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE key:214 0 -1
 1) "1"
 2) "1"
 3) "1"
```

Redis already displays the numbers as char. When I extract them, I also get chars:

```
val data: List[ChannelBuffer] = Await.result(redisClient.lRange(key, 0, -1))
val buffer: ChannelBuffer = data(0)
buffer.readChar() // 1
buffer.readInt() // 49
```

Is writing integers to a list possible with the cli client? And if not, will the following even work?

```
val key = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer("listkey", utf8)
val list: List[ChannelBuffer] = List(1,1,1).map { number =>
   val buffer = ChannelBuffers.buffer(4) // int sized buffer
   buffer.writeInt(number)
   buffer
}

// will this store the int's correctly??
redisClient.lpush(key, list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In redis most everything is a string. This is because of the protocol used. It's text-based, so it's impossible to tell number `1234` from string `"1234"`.

It *might* be storing integers internally, but you'll get strings anyway. You should cast your numbers in the app.